# Extending an existing Xamarin Forms app to Uno to enable it to run in a browser using WASM

Tags: xamarin, uno-platform

I am attempting to extend my Xamarin Forms app to Uno to enable it to run in a browser using WASM.  I am following the Xamarin Forms porting document at https://platform.uno/xamarin-forms. The article on that page entitled "Uno Platform for Xamarin.Forms Developers" has, as its Get Started, Step 1: Create a Xamarin.Forms project, Check “Place project and solution in the same directory”. My existing Xamarin Forms project (which I want to port) was not created with "Place project and solution in the same directory".  How can I port this project which was not created with "Place project and solution in the same directory".  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have reported the problem here - https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/3882

Answer (score 2):

To use Uno Platform renderers for Xamarin.Forms, you need to make sure you are using Xamarin.Forms version 4.5.0-uno.571.

Comment: Typo - version is  4.5.0.356